# c - dereferencing pointer to incomplete type - error with a pointer to a char*

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I have a problem accessing a char* that is in another struct, heres the code:

**User_Network.c:**

```
struct User_Networks_t {
    SocialNetwork network;
};

typedef struct User_Networks_t* User_Networks;


void aaa(User_Networks u1)
{
    u1->network->Name = "test";  /// ERROR: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 
}
```

Here is what I have in the **SocialNetwork.h**:

```
typedef struct SocialNetwork_t* SocialNetwork;
```

the struct that is in the **SocialNetwork.c**:

```
struct SocialNetwork_t {
    char *Name;
};
```

Why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define your struct `SocialNetwork_t` in the implementation file **SocialNetwork.c**, the compiler can not know about the contents of the struct when it is compiling **User_Network.c**, if you only use `#include <SocialNetwork.h` there. The compiler parses the header file **SocialNetwork.h** and knows that it should find the definition of the struct `SocialNetwork_t` later on, but doesn't encounter that definition when compiling the dereference in `void aaa(...)`. So, put the complete struct definition into **SocialNetwork.h**.

[update]
I'll elaborate a little bit more on that answer. I guess your file **User_Network.c** looks like this:

```
#include "SocialNetwork.h"
struct User_Networks_t {
    SocialNetwork network;
};

typedef struct User_Networks_t* User_Networks;


void aaa(User_Networks u1)
{
    u1->network->Name = "test";  /// ERROR: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 
}
```

When your compiler compiles this, the preprocessor substitutes `#include "SocialNetwork.h" with the content of that file, which gives you:

```
/* START content from the included file */
typedef struct SocialNetwork_t* SocialNetwork;
/* END */
struct User_Networks_t {
    SocialNetwork network;
};

typedef struct User_Networks_t* User_Networks;


void aaa(User_Networks u1)
{
    u1->network->Name = "test";  /// The struct SocialNetwork is not defined here
}
```

This will be the complete file when the compiler starts the actual compilation. So, when you try to access the `Name` field from `struct SocialNetwork`, the compiler didn't see the struct but only the typedef of a pointer type. Hence it can not know to which type you are actually referring.